# UIViewController before start the UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiview, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

I have a 3 tabs application in my iOS project, all I want is to start a simple UIView before the delegate loads all the TabBarController with the 3 tabs... Just like a "login" page **before** load the app.

Then, when the user has the permission, the application **dismiss the first UIView** and **show the tab bar views**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a modal view controller that is instantly triggered by the first tab in your tab bar.

You can use

```
[self presentViewController:startViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

in for instance viewDidLoad.

Comment: I used the presentViewController, and the UIViewController works, but I not see any view, it displays a black screen.

Comment: I got it, I use a [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"First"];